# Suspend a transactions using code with Example

Tags: axapta, point-of-sale, dynamics-ax-2012-r3, morph-x

I know that POS keeps all the suspended transactions in `SalesTransactions` table. And all the lines related to the transactions are kept in `TransactionsData` field of `SalesTransactions` table. My requirement is to create the transaction in `SalesTransactions` from backend using any code, but I am not able to do that because of `TransactionData` field.

Can anyone please guide how could I achieve it?

Do we have any example in Retail SDK?

Is there any possibility to do that?

Comment: Never put contact information in your question.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Actually I just copied the context from my file and paste it. Later I observed. Thank you for the correction.

Comment: Dear, do you have any workaround/solution about this post?